# How does MongoDB Update() method work?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Consider the mycol collectioin has following data.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("544946347db27ca99e20a95f"), "title" : "MongoDB Overview" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("544946357db27ca99e20a960"), "title" : "MongoDB Overview" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("544946377db27ca99e20a961"), "title" : "MongoDB Overview" }
```

Let us update the document.

```
>db.mycol.update({'title':'MongoDB Overview'},{$set:{'title':'New MongoDB Tutorial'}})
```

Which results in updation of the document.

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
> db.mycol.find();
```

Now when i try to find the docs in my `collection`, i see that the first document getting updated. I am confused on how the `updation works in mongodb` when there is a `duplication of documents`.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("544946347db27ca99e20a95f"), "title" : "New MongoDB Tutorial" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("544946357db27ca99e20a960"), "title" : "MongoDB Overview" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("544946377db27ca99e20a961"), "title" : "MongoDB Overview" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When multiple documents match the `update` criteria, only the *first* matching document is updated unless the [`multi`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter) option is used:

```js
db.mycol.update(
  {'title': 'MongoDB Overview'},
  {$set: {'title': 'New MongoDB Tutorial'}},
  {multi: true})
```